# Jquery nextAll and clone doesn't keep data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I have a table and I added some information to all of the rows with the jQuery data function, like this:

```
$(tr).data('info',info);
```

This is working fine, but here is the tricky part: if I click on a row, I clone the rest of the rows to another table, its working fine like this:

```
$(this).nextAll().clone().addClass('removeFirst').appendTo("table.playlists tbody");
```

However, I have the jQuery's .data() function on all of the rows, but its not getting cloned to the other table.

What should I do?

Comment: *What should i do?* Read the [`clone` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) carefully, you will find the answer there.

Comment: Hm, thanks, so i just have to add "true"

Comment: @FelixKling - you should write your comment as an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: clone elements AND events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989318/jquery-clone-elements-and-events)

Answer (score 1):

you must use clone(true) instead