# Jquery hover event stuck on clone elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, quicksand

I am creating an plugin with wordpress for the portfolio items. Everything works fine . But the issue is when i apply the filter the hover effect stopped working on the cloned items 
also available [JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/manojrudra/30cm7pzc/)

the jquery code is given below i tried

```
/* Scroll to Top Button */
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    // Animate Box Shadow on some elements
    // Add the overlay. We don't need it in HTML so we create it here



    // Clone portfolio items to get a second collection for Quicksand plugin
    var $portfolioClone = jQuery(".rudra-portfolio").clone(true);

    // Attempt to call Quicksand on every click event handler
    jQuery(".rudra-portfolio-filter a").click(function(e) {

        jQuery(".rudra-portfolio-filter li").removeClass("current");

        // Get the class attribute value of the clicked link
        var $filterClass = jQuery(this).parent().attr("class");

        if ($filterClass == "all") {
            var $filteredPortfolio = $portfolioClone.find("li");
        } else {
            var $filteredPortfolio = $portfolioClone.find("li[data-type~=" + $filterClass + "]");
        }

        // Call quicksand
        jQuery("ul.rudra-portfolio").quicksand($filteredPortfolio, {
            duration: 500,
            easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
        });

        jQuery(this).parent().addClass("current");

        // Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
        e.preventDefault();
    })
    jQuery(".port-li").click(function() {

            jQuery(this).find('.content-wrapper').slideDown();
    });

    jQuery(".overeffect").mouseover(function() {
        jQuery(this).find('.content-wrapper').slideDown();

    });



    jQuery("#portfolio-grid li").mouseleave(function() {
        jQuery('.content-wrapper').slideUp(500);

    });

});
```

hour effect is working fine for first and second time , but after that it stopped working .

**Update**

I also tried this [Jquery clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989318/jquery-clone-elements-and-events)

Comment: Try `on('hover',function(){});`

Comment: not working , My hover function is working , check js fiddle link in the question

Comment: That's giving you a clue not the exact answer and wow you solve it by yourself, nice for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by me ..

i just need to use this

```
jQuery(document).on('hover',".overeffect",function(){

     jQuery(this).find('.content-wrapper').slideDown();     
        });
```